# Can a Peryton Dive Attack and Multiattack in the same round?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

The Peryton has the following ability: "Dive Attack. If the peryton is flying and dives at least 30 feet straight toward a target and then hits it with a melee weapon attack, the attack deals an extra 9 (2d8) damage to the target." and also has the Multiattack action that allows it to make one Gore and one Talons attack. Can it dive for 30ft. and attack the target twice, with the first attack getting the damage bonus? Or does the dive mean it can only do a single melee attack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. **Dive Attack** is an ability that triggers when it says it does; it doesn't alter what the peryton is allowed to do. Since diving and then using **Multiattack** satisfies that condition (assuming at least one of the attacks hits), yes, it applies to whichever of the **Gore** or **Talons** attack triggers the Dive Attack ability's conditions. The peryton can then make its second attack before swooping past (or landing on the target, or whatever the plan is), since the Dive Attack doesn't prevent the second attack.