# Can a Wildshaped Druid trigger Dive Attack twice in a turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, lizardfolk

So I have a lizardfolk moon druid and I was curious about the interaction between his bonus action Hungry Jaws ability and the Dive Attack ability of the Quetzalcoatlus.

"Dive Attack. If the quetzalcoatlus is flying and dives at least 30 feet toward a target and then hits with a bite attack, the attack deals an extra 10 (3d6) damage to the target."

"Hungry Jaws. In battle, you can throw yourself into a vicious feeding frenzy. As a bonus action, you can make a special attack with your bite. If the attack hits, it deals its normal damage, and you gain temporary hit points (minimum of 1) equal to your Constitution modifier, and you can't use this trait again until you finish a short or long rest."

Now if I Dive Attack I can use my action to bite and receive the Dive Attack bonus damage.

My question is if I also use my bonus action Hungry Jaws to bite does it also benefit from the Dive Attack bonus damage?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, if you can increase your speed by at least 10 feet without needing to use your Action or Bonus Action to Dash.

Per Wild Shape:

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so. However, you can’t use any of your special senses, such as darkvision, unless your new form also has that sense.

Hungry Jaws is a "special attack with your bite", granted to you by your race, so you would still have access to it while Wild Shaped. There may be an argument to be made that "a special attack with your bite" is not "a bite attack", but I think the answer to that is that Hungry Jaws is eligible to benefit from Dive Attack.

You may run into an issue with speed, though. Dive Attack seems to only apply to a single bite attack, so you may have to dive 30 feet and use your Action, fly up 30 feet, then dive another 30 feet and use your Bonus action. The Quetzalcoatlus only has a fly speed of 80 feet. Thus we have to answer "does Dive Attack use 30 feet of movement," or more specifically "Is Dive Attack considered falling?" If Dive Attack is falling, then it's not a problem, but otherwise, the Quetzalcoatlus may not have enough movement to be able to benefit from Dive Attack twice in one turn.

I would argue that a Dive Attack is not considered falling since the attacking creature does not take damage. Per Falling in the PHB, page 183:

> At the end of a fall, a creature takes 1d6 bludgeoning damage for every 10 feet it fell, to a maximum of 20d6.

Additionally, per Flying Creatures and Falling from Xanathar's Guide to Everything, page 77:

> A flying creature in flight falls if it is knocked prone, if its speed is reduced to 0 feet, or if it otherwise loses the ability to move, unless it can hover or is being held aloft by magic, such as the fly spell.

Since Dive Attack is not any of those things, and the attacking creature doesn't take 3d6 bludgeoning damage, Dive Attack is most likely not considered falling, and therefore would take up movement, thus requiring a fly speed of at least 90 feet in order to apply the damage increase to both an Action and a Bonus Action. Multiclassing two levels into Monk would grant you +10 movement speed, or multiclassing two levels into Fighter would grant you Action Surge, which would let you Dash and make both attacks, so this is possible.

Comment: +1. Also, if there are multiple enemies spaced 10 feet apart (or more), you could Dive Attack both in the same turn

Comment: This seems to suggest that each bite attack needs a separate 30ft movement, is there a rule that you are basing that on? Is there anything to say that a single instance of a 30ft move wouldn't allow for an arbitrary amount of dive attacks assuming you had an appropriate amount of attacks?

Comment: @SeriousBri A very literal reading of Dive Attack, where the bite attack is singular. Also, the answer by SevenSidedDie here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58033/36334